# How to add a gradient in a Slider?

Tags: react-native

How can I add a gradient to a slider in react native?
Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faLAk.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using [react-native-linear-gradient](https://github.com/react-native-linear-gradient/react-native-linear-gradient) inside [react-native-multi-slider](https://github.com/ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider)'s code.

First use the slider anywhere.

```
import MultiSlider from '@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider'

<MultiSlider
  min={100}
  max={100000}
/>
```

Then navigate to MultiSlider.js file in the library, and look for `const body` inside `render` method.
Then replace this:

```
<View
    style={[
      styles.track,
      this.props.trackStyle,
      trackOneStyle,
      { width: trackOneLength },
    ]}
/>
```

With this:

```
<LinearGradient
    style={[
       styles.track,
       this.props.trackStyle,
       trackOneStyle,
       { width: trackOneLength },
    ]}
    colors={['white','chocolate']}
    start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
    end={{ x: 1, y: 0 }}
 />
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

I use another slider package [@miblanchard/react-native-slider](https://github.com/miblanchard/react-native-slider) and the [react-native-linear-gradient](https://github.com/react-native-linear-gradient/react-native-linear-gradient) to get the gradient slider result:

[Gradient Sliders Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RE1tm.png)

Here are the codes(for the upper slider):

```
<View>
<LinearGradient
  start={{x: 0, y: 0}}
  end={{x: 1, y: 0}}
  colors={[COLORS.BLACK, COLORS.WHITE, COLORS.WHITE]}
  style={styles.linearGradient}>
  <Slider
    minimumTrackTintColor={'transparent'}
    maximumTrackTintColor={'transparent'}
    thumbStyle={styles.brightThumb}
  />
</LinearGradient>
</View>
```

And for the styles:

```
linearGradient: {
  borderRadius: 20,
  height: 15,
  justifyContent: 'center',
},
 brightThumb: {
  backgroundColor: COLORS.WHITE,
  borderColor: COLORS.GREY,
  borderRadius: 10,
  borderWidth: 5,
  height: 20,
  width: 20,
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

you can customize the display by renderMinimumTrackComponent or renderMaximumTrackComponent Function when using  package @miblanchard/react-native-slider